# Firebase functions trigger seemingly randomly when using onWrite

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm using cloud functions to monitor new posts into the realtime database. Looking at the logs this function runs ... randomly maybe once out of every 10 messages. I see the messages coming in to the DB smooth like butter and I'm checking the correct node since it's at least running every once in a while.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.helloWorld = functions.database.ref('/messages/{messageId}')
    .onWrite(event => {
      console.log("run every darn time!");
});
```

This happening to anyone else?

Comment: The code looks fine. If you're certain your function is being triggered for 1/10 messages, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

Your listener might be timing out and causing some unexpected behaviour.

[Take a quick look at the documentation. The functions require a return statement to tell Firebase that they are finished executing.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions)

> Terminate a **synchronous** function with a `return;` statement.

```
exports.helloWorld = functions.database.ref('/messages/{messageId}')
  .onWrite(event => {
    console.log("run every darn time!");
    return Promise.resolve();
  });
```